# Is it possible to use a different database name with SqlMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, security, sqlmembershipprovider

Can I specify a different database than `ASPNETDB` using `SqlMembershipProvider`?  I am developing a site on a shared host, and have to restrict my data schema to a single provided database.

I was roundly scolded last time I suggested rolling my own authentication code.

Alternatively, is there some other packaged authentication system I could drop in and configure to use an arbitrary database and tables from asp.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the ASP.Net Membership Schema to any SQL database by using the [aspnet_regsql command line tool.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28VS.80%29.aspx)

You can also specify any connection string you'd like for your membership provider.  Simply add something like this to your membership declaration in your web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Database=MyDatabase;Server=xxx;User=xxx;Pwd=xxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings> 

<membership defaultProvider="MyProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="/Test"
    description="MyProvider" name="MyProvider" type="SqlMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is largely correct, but I had a problem until I fully qualified the "Type" value to be "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider".

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="MyProvider"
         applicationName="/Test"
         description="MyProvider"
         name="MyProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```